# Is there a way of listing all connections of Simulink GoTo-From pairings?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am currently working on a vehicle model in Simulink comprising of various subsystems (engine, transmission, etc)

Each subsystem has outports and inports, which are connected via GoTo and From blocks. I am using said blocks because there are multiple instances where one outport is connected to more than one inport.

Is there a way to list the connections of all GoTo and From blocks? I need the names of the GoTo and corresponding From blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [`find_system`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/find_system.html). Like this:

```
modelName = 'goto_from'; % or whatever
gotos = find_system(modelName, 'LookUnderMasks', 'all', ...
    'BlockType', 'Goto');
for idx = 1:numel(gotos)
    goto = gotos{idx};
    tag = get_param(goto, 'GotoTag');
    froms = find_system(modelName, 'LookUnderMasks', 'all', ...
        'BlockType', 'From', 'GotoTag', tag);
    fprintf('Goto block: <%s>, tag <%s>\n', goto, tag);
    fprintf('Matching from:\n%s\n', strjoin(froms, newline));
end
```